# KeyError issue while using pandas dataframe create from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have recently started to work in Python and pyspark. Please do not mind if the question looks lame.

Df is my datframe which was converted using pandas from a CSV file which has Real_XYZ_PQ_N0 named variable.

When I use the following line of code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_filename)

serial_id= df['sid'].unique()

for sid in serial_id:
    macros = macro_file[macro_file['sid'] == sid]

    df['Real_XYZ_PQ'] =(((df['Real_XYZ']/df.Real_XYZ.shift(3))**4)-1)*100
```

I get following error:-

KeyError: 'Real_XYZ'

I have this variable in my csv file and also when i use df.columns i get the Real_XYZ_PQ in result set. Although when i use df.head(5) i am not able to see the column Real_XYZ_PQ. Can somebody let me know what can be the possible cause. Can somebody also tell me what shift function here is doing to the result set.

I am running my code in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Post your `Df.head(5)` and your `Df.columns`

Comment: Please update the question with the code snippet

Comment: @RafaelC actually the code is for my office use and hence I can't put the actual data here. But yes when I did Df.head(5) I got to find that the error with which KeyError was coming, is not present. The command missed few columns and placed "..."  In their place. Although Dr.columns gave me all the columns.

Comment: @DipanshuShekhar I know, that is normal behavior for pandas. I just asked for `head` and `columns` so that we could see how your data frame is structured, otherwise is very hard for us to analyze the problem. I can only do some suggestions here...first suggestion is checking if there are whitespaces around your columns name. If there are, `Real_XYZ` yields a KeyError but `Real_XYZ ` with a space after would not.Second, is to check whether you have multi-indexes in your columns or not; depending on how its structured, it could also yield KeyError.Finally,check if the columns is, indeed, present

Comment: @RafaelC Thankyou for the response. I found the error in the column name.